# C++ - iterating through array of pointers causes errors

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, pointers, pass-by-reference

So I have two classes - Dvd and DvdGroup. DvdGroup basically manages an array of dvds and provide manipulative member functions for that class. I'm struggling with figuring out how to iterate through an array of pointers in C++. Basically for the DvdGroup function, its supposed to be copy constructor that performs a deep copy of the dvd group. It's purpose is to call the Dvd copy constructor to create a copy of each Dvd object.

However, when I try to do that, I get a number of errors

```
DvdGroup.cc: In copy constructor ‘DvdGroup::DvdGroup(DvdGroup&)’:
DvdGroup.cc:18:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘Dvd::Dvd(Dvd*&)’
   Dvd newDvd(dvds.dvdCollection[i]);

In file included from DvdGroup.h:5:0,
                 from DvdGroup.cc:5:
Dvd.h:10:5: note: candidate: Dvd::Dvd(Dvd&)
     Dvd(Dvd&);
     ^~~~~
Dvd.h:10:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Dvd*’ to ‘Dvd&’
Dvd.h:8:5: note: candidate: Dvd::Dvd(std::__cxx11::string, int)
     Dvd(string, int);
     ^~~~~
Dvd.h:8:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
DvdGroup.cc:19:24: error: cannot convert ‘Dvd’ to ‘Dvd*’ in assignment
   dvdCollection[i] = newDvd;
```

My for loop is supposed to do a very simple task, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I was wondering if anyone could help.

DvdGroup.cc file:

```
DvdGroup::DvdGroup(DvdGroup& dvds){ 
    numDvds = dvds.numDvds;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDvds; ++i){
        Dvd newDvd(dvds.dvdCollection[i]);
        dvdCollection[i] = newDvd;
    }
}
```

DvdGroup.h:

```
#ifndef DVDGROUP_H
#define DVDGROUP_H
#define MAX_DVDS 15
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DvdGroup
{
    public:
        DvdGroup(int);
        DvdGroup(DvdGroup&);    
        ~DvdGroup();
        void add(Dvd*);

    private: 
        Dvd* dvdCollection[MAX_DVDS];
        int numDvds;

};
#endif
```

The copy constructor from the Dvd.cc file:

```
Dvd::Dvd(Dvd& dvd){
    title = dvd.title;
    year = dvd.year;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of `Dvd*` pointers instead of an array of `Dvd` objects?  And why are you using a fixed-length array instead of using a `std::vector`?

Comment: This is extremely C-style C++. In C++ always use Standard Library containers like `std::vector`, and steer towards using `const` values instead of `#define`. If this just crashes out of the gate I'd check that you actually initialize the array (and frees it in the destructor), or better, rip that out and replace it with `std::vector<Dvd>` and get that part fixed permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the DVD collection *owns* the DVDs, in which case you need to make new copies via *new*, e.g.

```cpp
DvdGroup::DvdGroup(DvdGroup& dvds){ 
    numDvds = dvds.numDvds;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDvds; ++i){
        dvdCollection[i] = new Dvd(*dvds.dvdCollection[i]);
    }
}
```